# Monthly listviews android

Tags: android, listview

I have developed a listview that will store all the data from my database and colour the background of the listview child depending on a value entered to the database. I want to be able to show the data store in monthly listviews for comparison. Will I need to set up 12 different listviews?
Currently the code looks like this:

```
    Calms info = new Calms(this);
    info.open();
    String data = info.getFlareData();
    info.close();

    String arr[] = data.split("..\n\n");
    System.out.println(arr);

    ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arr){
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            TextView tv =  (TextView) super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            String str = tv.getText().toString();

            if(str.contains("High Severity"))
            {
                tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            }
            else if(str.contains("Low Severity"))
            {
                tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            }
            else if(str.contains("Medium Severity"))
            {
                tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(255, 186, 0));
                tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            }
            return tv;
        }
    };

    setListAdapter(ad);
```

Comment: sorry but I do not get it. What is your desired result?

Comment: I want to be able to view the data store in the same sort of way except split the information into monthly views

Comment: I would want to make a parent view that would have 12 children views that would display information from the database depending on which month it is

Comment: i would say that goig for 12 ListViews would be the less complicate way to address you otherwise intricate requirements. Sorry